# paypal checkout not working as wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, paypal

I wanted to add paypal to my site but it doesn't show the amount that is needed to be paid but rather an amount that a customer can enter at their will and get the product. My website is a assignment helper website where people has to choose in how many days and how many pages are needed to be done, so I can't put a specific price point as the user will enter the number of days and number of pages and the price will be calculated automatically and when forwarded to paypal payment page, it should show the price there which is to be paid. But in my website, when the user is forwarded to the checkout page, the user is asked to enter the amount which I don't want because if the user enters 1$ then I will have to give him/her the assignment for 1$ which original price would be 8$(assuming). So how do I make paypal know what price the user has to pay when they're send to the checkout page like automatically?

my order form page
[image: order page]

And also there are two pages, the first image shows a random image where the user is asked to enter the amount and it show al muhairi in the top. I have no idea what it is. [image: 1st image]

in the second page, it shows the amount which I entered for trail purpose and it is not the automated price which I wanted i.e 8$ 
Please help me solve this problem.. [image: 2nd image]

Here is the code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Section Start For Jquery Validatation Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jQuery.validator.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Section End For Jquery Validatation Scripts -->
<script>

function initalamout(){
  var pages=parseInt($('#selectPages').val());
    console.log('pages - '+pages);

    var amount_day1=pages * 8;
    var amount_day2=pages * 7;
    var amount_day35=pages * 6;
    var amount_day69=pages * 5;

    console.log(amount_day1);
    console.log(amount_day2);
    console.log(amount_day35);
    console.log(amount_day69);

    $('.litExpress').text("$"+amount_day1);
    $('.litFast').text("$"+amount_day2);
    $('.litStandard').text("$"+amount_day35);
    $('.litMinimal').text("$"+amount_day69);

    $('#express').val("$"+amount_day1);
    $('#fast').val("$"+amount_day2);
    $('#standard').val("$"+amount_day35);
    $('#minimal').val("$"+amount_day69);


}
function myDateFormatter (dateObject) {
        var d = new Date(dateObject);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

        return date;
    }
    function update_date_price(dateobj){

      var page=$('#selectPages').val();
       var str=dateobj;
       console.log("price in fncc= "+str);
        var res = str.replace("$", "");
        var res=parseInt(res);
        $('#lblamount').text("$"+res);
        $('#payamount').val(res);
        console.log("amount - "+res);
        var days=0;
        if((res%8)==0){
          days=1;
        }
        if((res%7)==0){
          days=2;
        }
        if((res%6)==0){
          days=5;
        }
        if((res%5)==0){
          days=9;
        }
        console.log("days-"+days);
        console.log("deadline - "+$("#deadlinehide").val());
         var date = new Date($("#deadlinehide").val());

         console.log("Date - "+date);
        if(!isNaN(date.getTime())){
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

            $("#datepicker").val(myDateFormatter(date));
        } else {

        }
    }
 $( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#fileupload').on( 'change', function() {
   myfile= $( this ).val();
   var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();

   if(ext=="pdf" || ext=="docx" || ext=="xls" || ext=="xlsx" || ext=="doc"){
       //alert(7);
   } else{
       alert("Invalid File Format Uploaded");
   }
});

    initalamout();
    $('#paypal-frm').hide();

//$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$('#deadlinehide').val(myDateFormatter(new Date()));
var rndval=Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000);
   $('#lblreference').text(rndval);
   $('#hdreference').text(rndval);
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
//             alert(dateText);
              var cost=dateText;
        console.log("cost - "+cost);
        $('#deadlinehide').val(cost);

        },  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
   }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    $('input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]').change(function() {

        $('#lblamount').text("$"+this.value);
        $('#payamount').val(this.value);
        console.log("val - "+this.value);
       update_date_price(this.value);


    });

    $('#selectPages').on('change', function() {

    var pages=parseInt(this.value);
    console.log('pages - '+pages);

    var amount_day1=pages * 8;
    var amount_day2=pages * 7;
    var amount_day35=pages * 6;
    var amount_day69=pages * 5;

    console.log(amount_day1);
    console.log(amount_day2);
    console.log(amount_day35);
    console.log(amount_day69);

    $('.litExpress').text("$"+amount_day1);
    $('.litFast').text("$"+amount_day2);
    $('.litStandard').text("$"+amount_day35);
    $('.litMinimal').text("$"+amount_day69);

    $('#express').val("$"+amount_day1);
    $('#fast').val("$"+amount_day2);
    $('#standard').val("$"+amount_day35);
    $('#minimal').val("$"+amount_day69);

//      $('#lblamount').text(this.value);


    update_date_price($('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked', '#main-frm').val());

    });


    $.validator.addMethod("birth", function (value, element) {
        var year = value.split('/');
        if ( value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/) && parseInt(year[2]) <= 1990 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    },"Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy.");


    $('#main-frm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
         errorClass: "invalid-msg",
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true                
            },

            email:{
              required: true,    
              email:true          
            },
            cemail:{
              required:true,
              email:true,
              equalTo: "#email"
            },
            subject:{
              required:true

            },
            message:{
              required: true,
              maxlength: 250
            },
            deadlinedate:{
              required: true,

            }

        }
      /*  submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            console.log('a');
            return false; // for demo
        }*/
    });

       $('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {

        if($("#main-frm").valid()){
        //$("#submit-btn").submit();  
        var paypalamount=$('#lblamount').text();
        var paypalitem=$('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked', '#main-frm').attr('id');
        var paypalreferencenumber=$('#lblreference').text();
console.log("--");
        console.log(paypalamount);
        console.log(paypalitem);
        console.log(paypalreferencenumber);
        //$('#paypal-amount').text(paypalamount);
        $('#am').val(paypalamount.replace("$", ""));
        //$('#paypal-item').text(paypalitem);
        //$('#paypal-referencenumber').text(paypalreferencenumber);

        alert('You Can Proceed For Paypal Checkout Now');
        //$("#submit-btn").hide();
        //$('#paypal-frm').show();

        if($('input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]').val()=="$8"){
          $('#planchoosen').val("Express");
        }
        if($('input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]').val()=="$7"){
         $('#planchoosen').val("Fast"); 
        }
        if($('input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]').val()=="$6"){
          $('#planchoosen').val("Standard");
        }
        if($('input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]').val()=="$5"){
          $('#planchoosen').val("Minimal");
        }
        $('#main-frm').submit();
        }
    });


    });

    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bmcbs3bo/

Sorry for poor english, not my native language